# Undetected if condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to use an if condition in conjuction with a for loop. I was confident this would work, but i'm seeming to have difficulty. I am able to print the information from the api, but when I try to if condition with results, something isn't getting detected.

Code:

```
for example in examples:
    profile = requests.get(api, params=params)
    hunter = json.loads(profile.content)

    accept_All = hunter['data']['accept_all']
    verif = hunter['data']['verification']['status']

    first_name = hunter['data']['first_name']
    last_name = hunter['data']['last_name']
    domain = hunter['data']['domain']
    email_address = hunter['data']['email']

    print(hunter['data']['verification']['status'])
    print(hunter['data']['accept_all'])

    if accept_All == 'False' and verif == 'valid':
        validEmails.append([first_name, last_name, domain, email_address])
        print("test")

print(validEmails)
print("Out of the Loop")
```

Output:

```
valid
False
[]
Out of the Loop
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: `accept_All` is probably the boolean value `False`, not the string `'False'`.

Comment: Is `hunter['data']['accept_all']` perhaps the Python value `False`, not the string `'False'`? Try changing `print(hunter['data']['accept_all'])` to `print(repr(hunter['data']['accept_all']))`; if it prints with quotes it's a string and your check is correct, if there are no quotes, it's `False`, and you should be testing `if not accept_All and verif == 'valid':`

Comment: @ShadowRanger the "if not" solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change to this,

```
if not accept_All and verif == 'valid':
    validEmails.append([first_name, last_name, domain, email_address])
    print("test")
```

Because `False` will be a boolean value, not a string.

Comment: Comparing to `False` is poor form (PEP8 warns against it), so `not accept_All` is the Pythonic approach. No need to leave both in there, just use the correct version from the start.